# adding a different class to css ul and li elements for navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that has two different UL elements in it, and each of them needs different CSS rules.  One of the UL elements is a menu bar and I keep trying to add a style name to it, so that I can differentiate it from the other UL element.  When I do the end result is a mess. I have hunted through this site and Google for hours but cannot find a solution, no matter which bits of the code I change.

The code that works for the menu without the class name is:

```
#menuBackground {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background:#0ab2aa;
width:100%;
height:50px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 999;
}
#menuContainer {
text-align: center;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin-right:1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
display:block;
min-width:120px;
height:50px;
text-align: center;
line-height:50px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#fff;
background:#0ab2aa;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 1rem;
}
.drop a{
display:block;
min-width:120px;
height:50px;
text-align: left;
line-height:50px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#fff;
background:#2f3036;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 1rem;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
background:#0ab2aa
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
background:#f3f3f3;
color:#2f3036;
height:40px;
line-height:40px
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
background:#0ab2aa;
color:#fff
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
position: absolute;
display:none
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
display:block;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
width:auto;
min-width:100px;
padding:0 10px
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden,.hidden:hover {
display:block
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
background:#0ab2aa;
text-align:left;
padding: 16px 0;
display:none;
width:100%!important
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
display:block;
margin:0 auto
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 1007px) {
/*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
ul {
position:static;
display:none;
white-space: initial;
}

/*Create vertical spacing*/
li {
margin-bottom:1px
}

/*Make all menu links full width*/
ul li,li a {
width:100%
}

/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
display:block
}
}
```

But when I try to add class names nav-li and nav-ul, if I change it to (one of many different attempts):

```
#menuBackground {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background:#0ab2aa;
width:100%;
height:50px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 999;
}
#menuContainer {
text-align: center;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.nav-ul{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.nav-li {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin-right:1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
.nav-li a {
display:block;
min-width:120px;
height:50px;
text-align: center;
line-height:50px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#fff;
background:#0ab2aa;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 1rem;
}
.drop a{
display:block;
min-width:120px;
height:50px;
text-align: left;
line-height:50px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#fff;
background:#2f3036;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 1rem;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
.nav-li:hover a {
background:#0ab2aa
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
.nav-li:hover, .nav-ul a {
background:#f3f3f3;
color:#2f3036;
height:40px;
line-height:40px
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.nav-li:hover, .nav-ul a:hover {
background:#0ab2aa;
color:#fff
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.nav-li, .nav-ul {
position: absolute;
display:none
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.nav-li, .nav-ul li {
display:block;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
.nav-li, .nav-ul li a {
width:auto;
min-width:100px;
padding:0 10px
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.nav-ul li a:hover + .hidden,.hidden:hover {
display:block
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
background:#0ab2aa;
text-align:left;
padding: 16px 0;
display:none;
width:100%!important
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
display:block;
margin:0 auto
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 1007px) {
/*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
.nav-ul {
position:static;
display:none;
white-space: initial;
}
/*Create vertical spacing*/
.nav-li {
margin-bottom:1px
}
/*Make all menu links full width*/
.nav-ul li, .nav-li a {
width:100%
}
/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
display:block
}
}
```

The display is wrong. (No navigation links can be seen in this version, but other versions have different errors)

The html code is:

```
<div id="menuBackground">
<div id="menuContainer">
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button" />
<ul class="nav-ul" id="menu">
<li class="nav-li"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-li">
<a href="about.php">About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-li">
<a href="#">Projects</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li class="drop"><a href="project1.php">Handyman</a></li>
<li class="drop"><a href="project2.php">Barrhill in Bloom</a></li>
<li class="drop"><a href="project3.php">Youth Club</a></li>
<li class="drop"><a href="project3.php">Coffee morning</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-li"><a href="hall.php">Hall</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-li"><a href="hall.php">Newsletters</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-li"><a href="meetings.php">Meetings</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-li"><a href="news.php">News</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-li"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I know that it is probably something simple, but I keep trying so many different things (I now have 24 versions of the CSS file) and nothing works.

I assume there must be a format for adding a class name to CSS code with multiple elements like `li ul li{}` but I cannot seem the find the way to do it. Changing it to `.nav-li, .nav-ul li{}` does not seem to work. This is driving me crazy.

I do hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Tog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the immediate child selector to style only certain nested elements:**

You don't actually need classes for the nav-ul and nav-li. If you want to do it only using CSS you can target only selected items using an immediate child selector ">". The immediate child selector will only affect the immediate children. i.e. If you do #menu > li. Only the immediate children(li items) of #menu will receive the styling:

This would mean that you can target the first level nav-li as:

```
#menu > li { 
...styling goes here 
}
```

Also, you can target the second level li as:

```
#menu > li > ul > li { 
...styling goes here 
}
```

This would make sure that your styles are separated for both the nested list elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Winston. That was exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `nav-ul` and `nav-li` classes on all your lists and list items, there are basically two things you need to do.

First, make sure all the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements in your HTML also have the right classes.

For example:

```html
<ul class="hidden">
<li class="drop"><a href="project1.php">Handyman</a></li>
```

...changes to

```html
<ul class="nav-ul hidden">
<li class="nav-li drop"><a href="project1.php">Handyman</a></li>
```

and so on.

Then you can rename all the `ul` and `li` selectors in your CSS to `.nav-ul` and `.nav-li`.

For example:

```css
li ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

...changes to

```css
.nav-li .nav-ul .nav-li {
    display:block;
}

/* Alternatively, if you prefer */
li .nav-ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

Hope it helps!